# Special Moodle SQL-Statement to get all managers and course-creators with firstname, lastname, course and mail

Tags: sql, moodle

Is it possible to make a SQL query in Moodle that will provide the following output for all course creators and managers

```
|coursecategory ID|coursecategory name| firstname|lastname|emailadress|rule (manager/coursecreator)|
```

If yes, what is the SQL statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT cc.id AS catid,
        cc.name AS catname,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname,
        u.email,
        r.name AS rolename
FROM mdl_course_categories      cc
JOIN mdl_context cx ON cx.instanceid = cc.id AND cx.contextlevel = '40' /* CONTEXT_COURSECAT */
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.contextid = cx.id
JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = ra.userid
```

Copied from
https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/ad-hoc_contributed_reports#Role_assignments_on_categories

Note that a user can have more than one role in a category, so you might want to use a group concat function

MySql - `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Postgresql - `string_agg()`